# NullPointerException in library when including org.openide.windows in a NetBeans plugin module

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, nullpointerexception

Some background: I'm trying to build a NetBeans plugin for NetBeans 7.3.1 - I have to work with this older version of NetBeans because this is for work, and the department won't allow us to mandate an upgrade to newer versions of NetBeans.

Anyway, I started a new project in a fresh install of NetBeans.  File->New Project, and I selected  NetBeans Module.  I include a new Action on the project, I follow the wizard to create it, as per the NetBeans plugin quick start tutorial (for the Google Toolbar tutorial [here](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-google.html)).  This much works.  Everything compiles and the plugin button appears as expected in the toolbar.

However, to do what I need, I have to include some outside libraries, notably org.openide.windows (via org.openide.windows.jar) among others.  As soon as I include this .jar file, I get a NullPointerException.  The error report/stack trace is here:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.WindowSystemImpl.load(WindowSystemImpl.java:79)
    at org.netbeans.core.GuiRunLevel$InitWinSys.run(GuiRunLevel.java:231)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
[catch] at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I have written absolutely no code.  My "code" is exactly as it would appear when you begin a new clean project from the NetBeans File -> New Project and select NetBeans Module.  So I don't know how it could be my code.  Since there isn't any.

What am I missing?  What can I do to fix this so I can write plugins?  Or is the library just broken?  I've tried multiple versions of this .jar library from multiple sources and nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with help from coworker.  Instead of adding the wrapped JAR package containing org.openide.windows to my project as a Wrapped JAR, we tried adding the package by name "Window System API" in Module Dependencies.  This worked.  Not sure why the various versions of org.openide.windows we found in JARs didn't work, and caused so much confusion to NetBeans, but adding the Module Dependency solved everything.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `compile time` try adding the `dependency` to `runtime` so that it wil be available both at compile time as well as runtime try adding it like

*File -> project properties -> libraries-> runtime libraries.*